# Interface optocouper with wide voltage range

Tags: opto-isolator, gpio, current-limiting

I need to interface optocopuler with my GPIO (3V Max) to detect presence of a wide voltage range in the optocopuer input (5V - 30V). After searching all different parts I have come up with this parts and circuit. Please let me know if it is a correct.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2XjOx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Datasheet of VOD207T http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/427/vod205t-537247.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Note. Edits on the question's schematics were performed when I was typing the answer. I will strikeout those considerations that are no more valid.

The circuit is fine except these considerations:

- (Minor) You wrote +4V on the logic side: I guess you meant 3V.
- (Critical) You're correctly using the 317 as current generator.  <s>However, with that resistors (R1 and R2 at 24 Ohm), the current is set to about 50mA, which is larger than the absolute maximum continuous forward current (30mA). The VOD207T works also with 10mA. You might need to adjust the resistor to 120 Ohm.</s> EDIT: now the current is 5mA. Maybe too low, see later.
- (Major) The output resistors are quite low (100 Ohm) <s>, especially  if you change the driving current</s>. EDIT: with a 5mA current and 100 Ohm, you can't have a 3V swing, as the minimum CTR (current transfer ratio) is 100%.  If you don't need a very high switching speed, you should consider to increase it to something about 330-470 Ohm (the larger, the better the low level, but the slower the switching speed). (EDIT: these values is calculated for 10mA current drive). Still, 100 Ohm will be too low, because the CTR min of that optocupler is 100%. With 10mA-input, you get a 10mA output, which corresponds to about only 1V-swing @100 Ohm.
- (Major) Be aware of power dissipation. At 30V, 1.2V falls in R1/R2, and about 1.2V on the LED of the optocoupler. This means that there are about 28V on the LM317L. It's thermal resistance Juction-to-Air is 160-180°C/W in TO92 package, i.e. quite high. At 10mA, the increase of the temperature between junction and air is 50°C. If you set a 20-mA current you have a 100-°C difference.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. I am lost now.. Trying to build a cost effective PCB, but this part of the design is driving me crazy.. Any alternate idea where I can do the same with a cheaper way.. BTW that +4V is not logic, that's my main voltage of the circuit and MCU is also driven with that voltage. Moreover I'll detect Logic LOW at the MCU. So, when the phototransistor is off, the GPIO is pulled up by R3 and when it is on, my GPIO will be low (Correct me if I am wrong). Now the power dissipation is really something to be worried about.. I am lost there :(

Comment: Do you need fast switching speed?

Comment: Not really. Speed does not matter.. I just want to be alerted when the external supply is on or off..

Comment: Sorry I confused the 317 with the optoisolator :) Change the "If you have 2 channels, you have a 100-°C difference." with: "If you set a 20-mA current you have a 100-°C difference.". Your optoisolator will be fine if there are 10mA!

Comment: Therefore the circuit you'have drawn is ok, and you won't have any problem. But change the 100 Ohm with 1k-2k Ohm  then. 

Still, I'm confused: why in the question you talk about 3V GPIO, but you use a 4V  VCC? What's the MCU voltage? 4V? or 3V?

Comment: Still 28V drop at the 317A is something to be worried.. The SMD package does not have a thermal pad as well. So not sure if I should go ahead.. Actually too hard to build a physical circuit with such tiny SMD components...

Comment: The MCU is a odd type itself.. LOL.. Its Quectels MC60. Its a combined GSM/GNSS/Bluetooth module with user program space. The MCU can operate between 3.3V to 4.6V and 4V is the typical suggested supply.. But surprisingly the GPIOs work within 2.8-3V. The datasheet does not tell about max and min source and sync current of the GPIO pins as well. I have written to the tech team of Quectel and waiting for their answer. Generally I believe it would be somewhere 10mA. I have no idea of the internal structure of the MCU.. :(

Comment: Just a small question, when the phototransistor is ON, what will be the voltage at GPIO, when I use a 2K resistor?

Comment: It will be close to 0. In fact, the current transfer ratio of that optocoupler is 100%. I.e. if you feed 5 mA to the LED you would have 5mA on the collector (provided that the transistor is in the active region. In particular, if VDD is high enough). However, since you have a 2-k pull-up resistor, the maximum current you could expect (assuming a 0 VCE) is 4V/2k = 2mA. In other words, that transistor is in saturation (low output voltage). Beware that, with RL = 2k (from Fig. 8 of the datasheet) the switching time will be about 40us!

Comment: Yes then my though is correct, about 8-9 milivolt according to my calculation.. So this circuit will definitely come within 1 dollar :) which is good enough for me.. Thank you very much for all of your guidance! I have just started with circuits and thus such silly questions.

Comment: BTW, I am going to use 120 ohms with LM317 to increase the current and replace that 100 ohms with 10K

Comment: You're welcome :) Check the datasheet to be sure that 10kOhm will grant you the speed you want!